# Wiping Activity stack

Tags: android

I'm implementing a not-so-standard navigational menu that is accessible from every screen in my app.  That is to say, from every screen in my app, I can pop up a menu that will let me choose an entirely different area of the app to navigate directly to.

I have several screens that I call edit screens. They are screens where the user had chosen an item from a list of items and are able to then edit the data for that item.  I do not wish for these screens to remain on the Activity stack if the user then uses the menu to navigate to some other area of the app.

This is easy enough.  I can simply call "finish()" before navigating away.  However, there are a couple places where it is possible to access a nested edit screen.  Meaning the edit screen the user is currently on is a child of a parent edit screen.  I want both off the Activity stack.

Can anyone think of a slick way to do this?  The only way I can think of is to always use startActivityForResult and pass back some identifier that tells the screen to kill itself the next time it resumes.

Comment: You can use Handler which will launch an activity and will destroy itself after some time or after certain task.